# Problems reading FileSystem in C++ (Boost not compiling)

Tags: c++, boost, mingw

I am attempting to write a C++ program that needs to recursively scan a directory for all files of a particular extension and get their filepath and data last modified.

From my research it appears that the recommendation from Stack OverFlow is to use the C++17 / "boost/filesystem.hpp" library to accomplish this.

I am using Code::Blocks 17.12 32 bit with MinGW GCC 5 32 bit on a 64 bit Windows 10 machine. This compiler does not recognize  as a built in library (rightly so, as that was not introduced until GCC 7). Is there a MinGW GCC 7 compiler available?

In absence of this compiler I attempted using an algorithm found here and it does not recognize any directory I put through it.

```
vector< pair<string, FILETIME> > searchDir(const string searchPath, const string searchStr) {
    // Function to get list of files and their last modified date from a directory
    cout << "searchDir(" << searchPath << ", " << searchStr << ")" << endl;
    string filePath;
    FILETIME lastEdit;

    vector< pair<string, FILETIME> > files;


    struct _finddata_t dirFile;
    intptr_t hFile;

    //if (( hFile = _findfirst( searchPath.c_str(), &dirFile )) != -1 )
    if (( hFile = _findfirst( "C:/", &dirFile )) != -1 )
    {
      do
      {
         if ( !strcmp( dirFile.name, "."   )) continue; // Don't iterate through self
         if ( !strcmp( dirFile.name, ".."  )) continue; // Don't iterate through parent dir
         if ( TRUE )
         {
            if ( dirFile.attrib & _A_HIDDEN ) continue;
            if ( dirFile.name[0] == '.' ) continue;
         }

         // dirFile.name is the name of the file
         string fileName = dirFile.name;
         cout << fileName << endl;
         int len = fileName.length();
         string ext = fileName.substr(len-4, len - 1);
         if ( !ext.compare(searchStr))
         {
            // Found a match
            FileTimes f(filePath);
            pair<string, FILETIME> file (filePath, f.getWritten());
            files.push_back(file);
         }


      } while ( _findnext ( hFile, &dirFile ) == 0 );
      _findclose( hFile );
    } else {cout << "Search Path not found" << endl;}



    return files;

}
```

With this failing I attempted to use Boost instead. I am able to compile programs in Code::Blocks using the prebuilt headers, but no library that needs to be compiled, and compiling fails saying that "gcc" is not a valid command.

The Directory that has gcc.exe is "C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin" and the directory that has boost is "C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_67_0"

I ran command prompt as administrator in the boost directory, assigned the gcc directory as my path variable, then tried to compile:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_67_0
path C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin %path%
bootstrap mingw
```

['gcc' is not a recognized as an internal or external command,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C38aj.png)

```
###
### Using 'mingw' toolset.
###

C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_67_0\tools\build\src\engine>if exist bootstrap rd /S /Q bootstrap 

C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_67_0\tools\build\src\engine>md bootstrap 

C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_67_0\tools\build\src\engine>gcc -DNT -o bootstrap\jam0.exe  command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c execcmd.c execnt.c filent.c frames.c function.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c pathnt.c pathsys.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c md5.c class.c cwd.c w32_getreg.c native.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c 

C:\Program Files\Boost\boost_1_67_0\tools\build\src\engine>exit /b 9009
```

In the end I am not particular to which of the three methods I get to work as I am writing 3 programs with shared libraries that will only be run on my machine, and another that is identical. I am not worried about portability or speed.

Thanks!

Comment: " Is there a MinGW GCC 7 compiler available?" -  yes, https://nuwen.net/mingw.html for example.

Comment: It appears this includes the new filesystem library under boost/filesystem and not as it's own library. Precompiled header files work fine, but it does not appear boost/filesystem is precompiled, and I still cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

PATH environment variable in Windows is a long string seperated with ;.
So when adding a new directory, your should add it with ; (semi colon).

```
path C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin; %path%
```

Comment: I added a semicolon to my cmd run statements as you specificed and now I get a new error [UnregisterWait not defined](https://imgur.com/a/I51f03O)

Comment: I added this to the cmd arguments but got the same error. What needs that variable set? Is it in the library somewhere itself?